# Algorithm for fine-grained locking of many resources

Tags: c, algorithm, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve the following problem:

Two cores both are trying to use a resource from a pool of many resources. In general they will not be using the same resources at the same time, but of course they might. Only in that case, one core should wait for the other core to finish. Otherwise they can/should do their work in parallel.

So the cores will be doing something like:

```
    lock(n);
    "do something with resource n"
    unlock(n);
```

Where n is the number of the resource, and there are many resources.

I already implemented some code that seems to work, but I really don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I'm afraid that my code contains some odd race-condition that will show up somewhere in the future. Does anybody know if there is a standard algorithm for this?

Best regards,

Arnaud

Comment: In what programming language are you trying to solve this?

Comment: My actual implementation is in C. However, I think the algorithm could/should be independent of a programming language.

Comment: Most languages have synchronization primitives that solve this problem. In case of C it probably (I'm not an expert) will be something platform specific - I recommend to add tag `C` to the question and look what people will respond. In any case custom solution will not be language independent and it would be "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: It might be slightly esoteric, but you might be interested in using software transactional memory for the problem. You could just put your "do something with resource n" line into atomic blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Taken at face value, you seem to be asking two things:

1. Is this a common pattern?
2. Am I doing it correctly?

To address #1, yes, this is common, but there is not to my knowledge a standard API or algorithm for doing this in C, especially when your resources are dynamically allocated. If you can pre-allocate your resources, and they are always accessed with an integer, you can simply do something like this:

```
#define N_RESOURCES 1024
#define lock_resource(n) pthread_mutex_lock(&(resources[(n)].mtx))
#define unlock_resource(n) pthread_mutex_unlock(&(resources[(n)].mtx))

struct resource *resources = calloc(N_RESOURCES, sizeof (*resources));
```

If `struct resource *` isn't an opaque pointer to you, and they are dynamically allocated, you can always do:

```
#define lock_resource(r) pthread_mutex_lock(&((r)->mtx))
#define unlock_resource(r) pthread_mutex_unlock(&((r)->mtx))
```

If it is an opaque pointer:

```
struct locked_resource {
    struct resource *r;
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
}
```

And use the above locking strategy.

If resources are dynamic and you need to initialize the lock when they're allocated and you cannot preallocate them, but you can set an upper limit to the number of resources you deal with, you can use a vector of locks and maintain a free-list. You could also use a [sparse array](http://research.swtch.com/sparse). Of course if the resources are also allocated concurrently, you'll have to protect your vector / free list / lock pool when resources are allocated / destroyed.

This may be the case you're trying to avoid, at which point it might just be worth asking whether you could better identify your work model in terms of queueing producers and consumers and use [a non-blocking data structure](http://concurrencykit.org/) instead.

To address #2, it's impossible to say because you haven't really demonstrated what you're actually doing. In that light, I somewhat doubt that this is the kind of answer you're looking for. In particular, it seems like your resources may be dynamically allocated and they could disappear at some point (perhaps making `lock(n)` result in undefined behavior).

If you can provide a better example, or show the code you are using to solve this problem, I (or someone) might perhaps be better able to answer your question.